# How can I use jQuery and Modernizr to add/remove menu items based on screen size?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, media-queries, modernizr

I've read a lot of Modernizr questions on here that involve Modernizr, jquery, and timeouts with resizing. I've played with many of them, and they tend to make it so the menu items are repeatedly added as you resize, over and over, until you're drowning in new nav items.

I just want to add and then remove a link from the main nav if the screen size changes. Add it when the size is below 768px, and then remove it when it's 768 and up. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try CSS media queries instead of jQuery

Make sure you put the meta tag in the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">



@media (min-width : 769px) {
  .main-nav .myLink {display:none;}
}

@media (max-width : 768px) {
  .main-nav .myLink {display:block;}
}
```